# Async, Awaiting in a awaited Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I've been trying to understand Async and await for a while now and am beginning to understand it mostly but am struggling with Awaiting in a awaited function.

I am asking this as I've had some weird behavior with async and am looking to understand it more.

```
public async Task FirstAsync()
{
    await SecondAsync();
    .
    .
    .
    doSomething();
}

public async Task SecondAsync()
{
    await ThirdAsync();
    .
    .
    .
    doSomething();
}
```

What I am struggling to understand with this example is, does FirstAsync continue when SecondAsync awaits ThirdAsync?

Comment: No. Since First task is waiting for Second Task to finish. And since second task is waiting for thirdtask to finish. then third task must finish, before second task can finish. So first task is waiting for both.

Comment: Instead, it's more accurate to say that FirstAsync() is awaiting the completion of SecondAsync(), but is not blocked while doing so.

Comment: I recommend starting with my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). It was written with the goal of explaining `async`/`await` to a point you can understand it sufficiently to use it correctly, but without getting bogged down in too many details.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am struggling to understand with this example is, does `FirstAsync` continue when `SecondAsync` awaits `ThirdAsync`?

No. If you will change the `FirstAsync` to:

```cs
public async Task FirstAsync()
{
    var task = SecondAsync();
    .
    .
    .
    doSomething();
    await task;
}
```

Then it will continue execution until the `await` is encountered.

In simple terms `await` means "stop current method execution and return to the caller and then continue when the awaited task is finished" (if the task has not completed yet), so `await SecondAsync();` will do exactly that, it will do exactly that.

Some potentially useful links:

- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Asynchronous programming doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)
- [Task asynchronous programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down, with some modifications to make things clearer:

```
public async Task FirstAsync()
{
    var secondTask = SecondAsync();
    await secondTask;
    doSomething(); // Will only be run after secondTask reaches "Completed" status    
}
```

So when does the task become completed? When the `SecondAsync` method either calls return explicitly, or reaches the end of the method block. So the order of execution will be exactly the same as if all the methods where non-async. Async just allow the thread to be used for something else while waiting.

But your confusion is understandable. `async` causes the method to be rewritten into a state machine for the task. This changes the meaning of `return`-statement from "return execution to the caller" to "mark the task as complete". The method will *actually* return when the first `await` is reached.

I would suggest reading [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) for a deeper understanding of what async and await does.